# How to see if a string contains a multiple substrings using indexOf()

Tags: java, substring, indexof

Im trying to scan a string(a username that the user types in), for a special character(!@#$%^&*_|?). However i believe indexOf scans for all those characters instead of finding just one. Heres my code:

```
     System.out.println("Please choose a user name, it must contain a special charcter and can include spaces");
    String user;
    String spe = "[^!@#$%^&*(){}><?~*]"; //Chars i want to be accepted
    user = input.nextLine();
     int signin3 = user.indexOf(spe);
     if (signin3 != 0) { //If there there is a chararacter
       System.out.println("Correct");
     } else //If there is no character
       System.out.print("Thats not correct, maybe try one of these at the end: " + user + "123! or" + user + "abc? or" + user "Honda$" );
```

The issue im having is that when ever i type in a special character, it still outputs the else, and it only works when i type in all those characters which is not how i want it to work, anybody knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: no not `!= 0`. It returns `-1` if nothing found.

Comment: ...as the documentation would have told you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as said in the comments, indexOf returns -1 when it dosen't find what its looking for, not 0.

I have no doubt you didnt really search for a solution online before asking this question... but anyway, the solution i recommend is using a matcher.

```
    System.out.println("insert username");
    String user;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]"); //Chars to look for
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    user =scan.nextLine();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(user); //Matching the pattern(what you wanna look for) and the username
    boolean b = m.find();
    if (b==true) { //If there there is a chararacter
       System.out.println("Correct");
     } else //If there is no character
       System.out.print("Thats not correct, maybe try one of these at the end: " + user + "123! or" + user + "abc? or" + user+"Honda$" );
```

Comment: I did, somebody in the comments gave me the aswer, switch user and spe and use -1, I actually searched on the internet for a simple fix couldnt find any specific answer, as im not really ready to use boolean yet. but thanks

Comment: I got to ask- what do you mean by not ready to use boolean? I even simplified it and said `if (b==true)` while i could just write `if(b)`.